# CamemBERT,'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2260' with BertLMDataBunch.from_raw_corpus

Tags: python, encoding, bert-language-model

Hello I'm trying in implement Cammebert on french texts, these texts are long, sometimes complicated because they can contain mathematics formulas, url,....
they are encoded in utf8.
to implement BertLMDataBunch.from_raw_corpus, I need to pass texts information in a list of strings.

[image: Text example]

```
databunch_lm = BertLMDataBunch.from_raw_corpus(
                data_dir=DATA_PATH,
                text_list=all_texts,
                tokenizer='camembert-base',
                batch_size_per_gpu=16,
                max_seq_length=512,
                multi_gpu=False,
                model_type='camembert-base',
                logger=logger)
```

[image: error message]

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you missing an "-" Between UTF and 8 at the decoding?

You can find it in your image at entry 65.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error, and the solution that worked for me was to navigate to the file data_lm.py located in this path:

> C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\envs\packages\Lib\site-packages\fast_bert\data_lm.py

In the file, I made a simple change: I replaced `with open(target_path, "w") as f:` with `with open(target_path, "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:`. After making this modification, the issue was resolved.

[Where to change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CK4zY.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).